# Finding depressed equation without a divisor

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been given

> $$4x^3 -2x^2 + x - 3 = 0$$

and I want to convert it into a depressed equation. A depressed equation is an equation that results from reducing the number of roots in a given equation with one unknown by dividing the original equation by the difference of the unknown and a root. However; I know for a fact that you need some sort of divisor in order to do this. The correct answer is:

> $$4x^2 + 2x + 3$$

Comment: @egreg That was my fault, but I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: By inspection I see that $x=1$ is a solution to the original equation. What binomial factor does that guarantee for the cubic?